# How to close window in vaadin?

Tags: java, window, vaadin

I have got class MyCustomWindow which extends Window (com.vaadin.ui) from vaadin.
When you click some button MyCustomWindow will show.
Now I would like to add button to this window and when you push this buton it will close the window.
I have got problem what to use to remove this window.
I have found:

```
Window w = getWindow();
getApplication().removeWindow(w);
```

or

```
Window w = this.findAncestor(Window.class);
w.close();
```

But it doesn't work.
I would like to remove window from inside the class, not from outside, using "this"? Something like:

```
UI.getCurrent().removeWindow(this);
```

I am using vaadin 7.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Hello if you want to close the window from inside your click listener you can do one of the following two things:

```
yourButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
                MyCustomWindow.this.close();
            }
        });
```

Or:

```
yourButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
                closeMyCustomWindow();
            }
        });

private void closeMyCustomWindow(){
   this.close();
}
```

closeMyCustomWindow() this function is inside the MyCustomWindow class.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code to remove all windows.

```
for (Window window : UI.getCurrent().getWindows())
        {

            UI.getCurrent().removeWindow(window);
            window.close();
        }
```

However if you already have reference to the window all you need is this:

```
UI.getCurrent().removeWindow(window);
```

Comment: It's good, but I would like to remove window from inside the class, not from outside, using "this"?

Comment: You can call UI.getCurrent() from any class.

Comment: You can use this loop from anywhere and it will remove all windows.

Comment: I would like to do something like: UI.getCurrent().removeWindow(this); I don't want to remove all windows just one in which "I am in".

Comment: You can only do that if 'this' is your window

Comment: I have got a class window and in this class there is a button and when user click this button the window should close/disappear/remove. Button has got a listener and in this function (listener) I need to add something like UI.getCurrent().removeWindow("this");. It is not good to remove all windows?

Comment: To sum up this is solution, but not efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can not modify windows while iterating. Copy the collection first.

```
for (Window window : new ArrayList<>(UI.getCurrent().getWindows())){
   window.close();
}
```

Removing windows while iterating on getWindows will throw concurrent modification exception.